# How do I use the label for the "available value for a parameter " in SSRS in a query(i.e using a new Dataset)

Tags: reporting-services

My apologies if that is a confusing question. I will include pictures to say what I mean. I have a parameter, called ResponseRange, where I specify the available value for that parameter- as shown below:

[image]

But in another parameter, called ClientResponseRange , I want to reference the *label* of the parameter value chosen previously. I've tried various options, but I wind up with errors...

So what I want to do is reference the label in a query, like below(sorry about code being unorganized)

[image]

Edit: I think I found a way!! 
I will make the last parameter have the following:

=Parameters!ResponseRange.Label

And *then* I can use that value in the dataset query - ie just say @ClientResponseRange   . OK keepin fingers X'ed

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

Setting the `@ClientResponseRange` parameter in your SQL to `Parameters!ResponseRange.Label` using an equation is the best way.